# If we are using union, then how to display table name with specific entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

Like I am using union of multiple tables and displaying rows ordered by date with some limit. But I also need to show that specific entry belong to a 'table' table. How to get value of 'table'?

Comment: SELECT 'first_table' source...

Comment: -1 for what I perceive as impoliteness towards another respondent below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easy

```
$sql = "
        SELECT col1, 'table1' , col2, col3 FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT col1, 'table2' , col2, col3 FROM table2
        UNION
        SELECT col1, 'table3' , col2, col3 FROM table3

    ";
$query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)){
```

Answer (score 3):

While mentioning required columns you can add another column which will have the name of table.

Like:

```
    SELECT *, 'table1' as table_name FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT *, 'table2' as table_name FROM table2
```

Doing this you can have table identifier in `table_name` column of the result set and you can use it as you want.

Comment: That's the obvious way nikhil. You think I haven't thought of that before? Actually, I don't want to increase table memory but still get the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 'table1' FROM `table1`
UNION
SELECT *, 'table2' FROM `table2`
```

Comment: You should give it an alias

Comment: Uday Hiwarale shoud give it an alias if he needs one. He should also enumerate the columns explicitly. I concentrated my answer on the requirement to *show that specific entry belong to a 'table' table*.